# SQL Nesting Logic Needed

Tags: sql

I have a situation where I need to build a query that pulls gives me a list of member that used an item on their account in timeframe one but that did not use on item on their account in timeframe two.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SS.memid
FROM SS
INNER JOIN SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid
INNER JOIN MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON SS.productid = PRODUCTS.productid
INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid
    AND NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT SS_1.memid
            FROM SS AS SS_1
            INNER JOIN SSUSED AS SSUSED_1 ON SS_1.ssid = SSUSED_1.ssid
            INNER JOIN MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS_1.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid
            INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS PRODUCTS_1 ON SS_1.productid = PRODUCTS_1.productid
            INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS AS PRODUCTCATS_1 ON PRODUCTS_1.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS_1.productcatid
            INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES AS EMPLOYEES_1 ON SSUSED_1.employeeid = EMPLOYEES_1.employeeid
            WHERE 
                MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite
                AND SSUSED_1.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek2
                AND @rvEndWeek2
                AND PRODUCTS_1.productcatid IN (27,28,29,58,77,75,30,61,31,32,47,68)
        )
WHERE MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite
    AND SSUSED.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartWeek1
    AND @rvEndWeek1
    AND PRODUCTS.productcatid IN (27,28,29,58,77,75,30,61,31,32,47,68)
```

The issue that I am running into is that when I try the query this way I get the following error:

Comment: I mean, it just looks like you are missing the schema in your reference. Hard to tell because it also looks like you removed it from your code when you pasted here.

Comment: Curious what the error is, although I assume it has something to do with that misplaced `NOT EXISTS`. I suspect that `NOT EXISTS` should be replaced with `Employees.employeeid NOT IN`.